# How to fetch a specific single post from Google feed reader

Tags: angularjs, rss, feed, rss-reader, google-feed-api

I am building an angular JS feed reader based on this tutorial http://dailyjs.com/2013/04/11/angularjs-1/.

I want to customize the Feed reader to fetch a specific post instead of the latest 10 posts or the most recent 1 post. Is this possible?

I saw there is a feed directive as well http://siddii.github.io/angular-feeds/app/ but I am unable to get it to work with a specific post.

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use this [Angular module](https://github.com/superfeedr/angular-superfeedr), which lets you display RSS feeds in your angular application.